# Compute the length of a clang::attr

Tags: clang, llvm

I'm working on a project that uses the Clang AST matcher to locate interesting attributes (e.g., "__boo__") on variable declarations and then uses `clang::Replacement` to change its spelling (e.g., "__foo__"). In order to construct a valid `clang::Replacement` object, I've succeeded to get the attribute location as follows.

```
auto &SM = getCompilerInstance().getSourceManager();
clang::SourceLocation sl = SM.getExpansionLoc(Attr->getLocation());

//Construct the replacement object
clang::tooling::Replacement Rep(SM, sl, length, "__foo__"); //?? how to compute the length of Attr
```

My question is how I can get the length of the attribute I want to change (, as programers are free to define whatever attributes they want).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the following working solution:

```
      auto &SM = getCompilerInstance().getSourceManager();
      clang::SourceLocation sl = SM.getExpansionLoc(Attr->getLocation());
      clang::LangOptions langOps;
      SmallString<256> buffer;
      StringRef sp = clang::Lexer::getSpelling(sl, buffer, SM, langOps);
      unsigned length = sp.size();
      ct::Replacement Rep(SM, sl, length, rep);
```